# UWP roamingdata Does not async

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I make a uwp app to share data between windows 10 PC and my windows 10 mobile Phone.next is the code:

```
    public static StorageFolder roamingFolder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
    public async static Task WriteToRoamingDataAsync(string str)
    {
        StorageFile savedFile = await roamingFolder.CreateFileAsync("dataFile", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(savedFile, str);
    }

    public async static Task<string> ReadRoamingDataAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile savedFile = await roamingFolder.GetFileAsync("dataFile");
            return await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(savedFile);
        }
        catch
        {
            return "-1";
        }
    }
```

I changed the data in my PC(input a string like "here is the data"), and i can read it in my PC.But when I deployed it on my Phone, i can't read the data that I had written on the PC,it always give me a "-1",I waited for 2 hours,the mobile app also gives me a "-1".

I think maybe should upload my app to Windows Store so I can get the wright effect.But I need to test the function before upload.

Here is somethings I should declare because I found some answers that can't solve my problem:

1. I closed the app on PC before i open the app on mobilephone.
2. I used the same hotmail account in PC and mobilephome.

At last ,Thank you for your help!

Comment: when you publishing to store on "distribution and visibility" section you can choose option to hide app (let it be visible by direct link only). this way you can test it